# Clear Text from UltraGridCell when Data is not Valid

Tags: string, vb.net, decimal, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm trying to add some validation into my `UltraGrid`, whereby if the user types a value into one cell, but has not set the value of a `CheckBoxColumn` to `True`, a `MessageBox` gets displayed and the text/value in that cell is cleared, leaving a blank cell again.

What I have so far is:

```
Try
    If e.Cell.Column.Key = "Commission_Rate" Then
        If e.Cell.Row.Cells("Commission_Override").Value = False Then
           MessageBox.Show("Before entering a custom rate, please set 'Commission Override' to True", "Override Commission", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            e.Cell.Value = ""
        End If
    End If
Catch
End Try
```

The `MessageBox` line works fine, however, another one is then displayed saying

> "Unable to convert from: System.String to System.Decimal"

The cell is a decimal cell, because it's for entering a monetary value, so how do I set the value to "" for `Decimal`?

Comment: Such columns are usually typed; in this case the db Column it maps to requires a numeric (decimal), so "0" or some such would be required.  Also the DGV at any rate provides for RowValidation` its not clear where that is

Comment: @Plutonix When the grid is loaded, it displays nothing, is there not a way to delete the typed character?

Comment: _e.Cell.Value = Nothing_

Comment: @Steve that didn't return the second `MessageBox`, but it didn't reset the value either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are getting from the database when no value is provided is DBNull.Value. So if you need the cell to show nothing you need to set same value like this:

```
e.Cell.Value = DBNull.Value
```

This will force the grid to show an empty cell

[Edit]
Use this code in BeforeEnterEditMode event to suppress user from editing a cell when the related check box cell is not checked:

```
    Private Sub UltraGrid1_BeforeEnterEditMode(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles UltraGrid1.BeforeEnterEditMode
    Dim cell As UltraGridCell = Me.UltraGrid1.ActiveCell
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    Try
        If cell.Column.Key = "Commission_Rate" Then
            If cell.Row.Cells("Commission_Override").Value = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Before entering a custom rate, please set 'Commission Override' to True", "Override Commission", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This almost works... It returns the `MessageBox`, and after pressing 'OK', the value entered remains in the cell, until I then edit another cell in the grid.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "This almost work". If you set the value of the cell to DBNull.Value it will show nothing in the cell as you said you need. However, I am not sure also in which event you are calling all this code. If you share some more information about your context we may try to give you a solution :)

Comment: Hi, I have this code in the `CellChange` event, which may be where the issue lies? Does it need to be in `BeforeRowUpdate`/`AfterRowUpdate`?

Comment: Ok, the best place, from my point of view, to do this is in BeforeEnterEditMode event. In this event, you will be able to check the checkbox and do not allow the cell to enter edit mode if the related check box is not checked. I added a code snippet to my answer which should do the trick

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I can modify this if I need to, but this is the basic functionality that I needed